# Return empty string or 0 (zero) in case of missing key with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am having problems with my json to csv conversion.

I have json file of this structure:

```
{
    "key": [
        {
            "key1": 1,
            "key2": 1,
            "key3": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 2,
                "3": 3,
                "4": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "key1": 2,
            "key2": 2,
            "key3": {
                "2": 2
            }
        }
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

I was using this jq call to convert my json to csv:

```
bin\jq-win64 ".key[] | [.key1, .key2, .key3.\"1\", .key3.\"2\", .key3.\"3\", .key3.\"4\" ] | tostring] | join(\";\")" source.json > output.tmp
```

I can't use standard `@csv`, because it's not good for my locale settings. But back to the problem. In some cases `key3` might not be full 4 element object (4 is the max with keys 1/2/3/4, just like in example). I have a problem with those missing subkeys, because jq returns "null" and that does not work well with CSV evaluation in excel or calc. Is there a way to force empty string or numeric 0 as output in such case?

In the end, I can try using some other command line text processor, but I'd be glad if I could do that with single tool.

EDIT:
I had the wrong json structure example and now the actual problem has changed a bit. Message is updated.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON data. Array elements don't have key. Moreover, inside an object, keys must be quoted. Please update your sample showing the different cases you want to tackle.

Comment: Thanks, that was a bad mistake on my side. I've used some pretty json visualizer and mistook the actual structure. So yes, key3 does not hold an array, but an object with up to 4 elements, but I still have problem, yet a bit different. Luckily it is solvable without jq, but maybe there is a way to do that with jq only, so I am leaving my question open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could tweak your pipeline by adding

```
map(. // 0)
```

right after forming the array.  If you want to preserve `false`, then you would have to add

```
map(if . == null then 0 else . end)
```

instead.

If you wanted a solution that was agnostic about the key names, you could use something along the lines of:

```
def resize($n): [range(0;$n) as $i | .[$i] // 0];
```

This would truncate or expand the input array.  If you don’t ever want to truncate, then tweak accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I had no time to test it earlier. First version did not work. With second one, I had some trouble in the beginning, but I've updated it to `map(if . == \"null\" then \"0\" else . end)` and it worked. Probably windows command prompt incompatibility :) Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @SoulReaver - `null` is converted to `"null"` by `tostring`, so it looks like you were testing for `null` in the wrong place. Of course it might be acceptable or even desirable to test for `"null"` ...